# Get the indices of the least often occuring values in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function that returns a numpy array of integer labels, for example:

```
labels_array = numpy.array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 3,])
```

The labels always run consecutively starting at 0.

My goal is to find the indices of the labels in the labels_array that occur the least often. If there are several labels in labels_array that satisfy that condition, then I want to get all the corresponding indices. For the above example, I would obtain

```
result= [6, 7, 9, 10]
```

and not just [6]

Currently I count the number of occurrences of each label, then get the indices of the ones that occur the least.

```
occurrencePerLabel = numpy.bincount(labels_array)
labels = numpy.where(occurrencePerLabel == occurrencePerLabel.min())
```

Now I have

```
labels = (array([2, 3]),)
```

telling me that 2 and 3 are the labels that occur the least often in labels_array

Next, I need to get the indices at which labels_array is 2 or 3 and that would be exactly the result I'm looking for. Basically I'm looking for something like

```
labels_array.index(labels_array == labels)
```

How do I do this with numpy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(labels_array, [2, 3]))[0]
array([ 6,  7,  9, 10])
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about np.in1d, it does exactly what Ineed!

Answer (score 1):

not pretty but it does the trick...`numpy.nonzero(numpy.sum([labels_array == l for l in labels[0]], axis=0))`